# Android Studio onTouchListener not working on Viewpager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

my ontouchlistener is not working. I try to put it on a viewpager to count basicly all touches the user does.

in my onCreate method:

```
   mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("TOUCH ON TAB", "TOUCH DETECTED");

                        if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            touchCounter++;
                        }

                        if(touchCounter >= 5) {
                            // you have done 5 touches
                            ShowCounter();
                            touchCounter = 0;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

But `Log.d("TOUCH ON TAB", "TOUCH DETECTED");` is not found in the console. Also my counter is not working.

The Viewpager looks like this:

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Have you considered using an `OnClickListener` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your problem is not on the `OnTouchListener`, I faced issues when I use spaces in the log tag when trying to log messages; they won't give you errors or warning, and if you don't filter out results in logcat and see the entire debug message, actually you'll find them there; but for some reason they can't be filtered right using the logcat filtering.

So try to change below log

```
Log.d("TOUCH ON TAB", "TOUCH DETECTED");
```

Into something without spaces or special characters

```
Log.d("TOUCH_ON_TAB", "TOUCH DETECTED");
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your custom class which extends ViewPager:

```
public class ViewPagerExample extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

public ViewPagerExample(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
    changePagerScroller();
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(@Nullable PagerAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    this.adapter = (ViewPagerAdapter) adapter;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}


public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}


private void changePagerScroller() {
    try {
        Field mScroller = null;
        mScroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        mScroller.setAccessible(true);
        ViewPagerScroller scroller = new ViewPagerScroller(this.getContext());
        mScroller.set(this, scroller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "error of change scroller ", e);
    }
}

private class ViewPagerScroller extends Scroller {

    private int mScrollDuration = 1000;

    ViewPagerScroller(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mScrollDuration);
    }
    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mScrollDuration);
    }


}
```

}